# How do I get my server.js to access redux values?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-redux, mongodb-atlas

I have a checkout page for a store that has some inputs such as address, name, etc. I also want to upload the cart info to the mongodb as well, but it's not working. The cart info comes from redux using the useSelector from redux, but I can't put that function into server.js. Does anyone have any tips? I have provided the schema below as well.

Server.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const productRoutes = require('./routes/productRoutes');
const CustomerInfo = require("./models/customerInfo");

connectDB();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api/products', productRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


//app.post

app.post ("/", function(req, res) {
    let newCustomerInfo = new CustomerInfo({
        fname: req.body.firstName,
        lname: req.body.lastName,
        email: req.body.email,
        phone: req.body.phoneNumber,
        address: req.body.address,
        city: req.body.city,
        district: req.body.district,
        section: req.body.section,
        confirmCode: req.body.confirmCode,
        comments: req.body.extraInfo,
        cartItems: req.body.cartcount
    });
    newCustomerInfo.save();
    res.redirect("/");
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Running on port ${PORT}`))
```

CheckoutScreen.js

```
import './CheckoutScreen.css';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// Components
import CartItem from '../components/CartItem';


const CheckoutScreen = () => {

    const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart);
    const { cartItems } = cart;

    const getCartCount = () => {
        return cartItems.reduce((qty, item) => Number(item.qty) + qty, 0)
    };

    const getCartSubTotal = () => {
        return cartItems.reduce((price, item) => item.price * item.qty + price, 0)
    };
    return (
        <div className="checkoutscreen">
            <div className="checkout__left">
                <body>
                    <form className="checkout-form" method="post" action="/">
                        <label className="input">
                            <input type="text" name="firstName" required/>
                            <span className="placeholder">First Name</span>
                        </label>
                        <label className="input">
                            <input type="text" name="lastName" required/>
                            <span className="placeholder">Last Name</span>
                        </label>
                        <label className="input">
                            <input type="text" name="email" required/>
                            <span className="placeholder">Email</span>
                        </label>
                        <label className="input">
                            <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" required/>
                            <span className="placeholder">Phone Number</span>
                        </label>
                        <label className="input">
                            <input type="text" name="address" required/>
                            <span className="placeholder">Address</span>
                        </label>
                        <label className="input">
                            <input type="text" name="city" required/>
                            <span className="placeholder">City</span>
                        </label>
                        <label className="input">
                            <input type="text" name="district" required/>
                            <span className="placeholder">District</span>
                        </label>
                        <label className="input">
                            <input type="text" name="section" required/>
                            <span className="placeholder">Section</span>
                        </label>
                        <label className="input">
                            <input type="text" name="confirmCode" required/>
                            <span className="placeholder">Confirmation Code</span>
                        </label>
                        <label className="input">
                            <input type="text" name="extraInfo" required/>
                            <span className="placeholder">Details/Comments</span>
                        </label>
                        <p className="cartcount">{getCartCount()}</p>
                        <button>Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </body>
            </div>
            <div className ="checkout__right">
            <div className="checkout__info">
                    <p>Subtotal ({getCartCount()}) items</p>
                    <p>${getCartSubTotal().toFixed(2)}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};



export default CheckoutScreen;
```

customerInfo.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const customerInfoSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    fname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    district: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    section: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    confirmCode: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    comments: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    cartItems: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

const customerInfo = mongoose.model('Customer Info', customerInfoSchema);

module.exports = customerInfo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your API in Server.js. To call the API you need to submit the form and handle the form submission by `handleSubmit` method on form `onSubmit` event. In handleSubmit method you need to call checkout action and pass the cart object. The `CheckoutAction` need to use `redux-thunk` to call server api asynchronously (side effect with middleware). Once the response back you can return the state by dispatching to `CheckoutReducer`

**CheckoutScreen.js**

```
import { Checkout } from '../action/checkoutAction'
const dispatch = useDispatch();

...........

const handleCheckout = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  dispatch(Checkout({ type:'CHECKOUT', payload:cart }));
}

......

<form className="checkout-form" method="post" action="/" onSubmit={e => handleCheckout(e)}>
```

**CheckoutAction.js**

```
export const Checkout = data => async dispatch => {
  let response = await axios.post(server_api_url, data);

  dispatch({ type: 'checkout_success', payload:response.data}); //to checkout reducer
}
```